# echo "something" > file not working when sh script is being executed by remote PHP server

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, php

I've got a web-server with my hardcoded webpanel for Source server management and I've got my VPS on CentOS which doesn't really want to execute sh script when asked from remote server.

Web-server and CentOS Server are not on a same server!!!

I got this SH script:

```
#! /bin/bash

SERVER_PORT="xxxx"
SERVER_IP="xxxx"
SERVER_MP="xxxx"
SERVER_MAP="xxxx"
SERVER_GAME="xxxx"

# CODE

OLDID=`cat pid_file 2> /dev/null`
if [ "$OLDID" != "" ]; then
    screen -X -S $OLDID quit
    rm -f pid_file
    sleep 1
fi

if [ "$1" != "stop" ]; then
    PORT_CHECK=`netstat -tuln | grep $SERVER_PORT`
    if [ "$PORT_CHECK" == "" ]; then
        UNIQID=`date +%Y%M%d%H%M%S`
        echo $UNIQID > pid_file
        screen -A -m -d -S $UNIQID ./srcds_run -console -game $SERVER_GAME -ip $SERVER_IP -port $SERVER_PORT -maxplayers $SERVER_MP +map $SERVER_MAP
        echo "true"
    else
        echo "false"
    fi
fi
```

And I got this PHP script which executes script above:

```
include('classes/ssh.class.php');
$ssh = new SSH2($ssh_server, $ssh_port); 
if (!$ssh->auth($ssh_user, $ssh_password))
die('nologin');
$ssh->exec("sh /home/...../...../za.sh");
echo $ssh->output(); 
die();
```

This is what I get on $ssh->output()

> No screen session found. true

When script is executing pid_file is not being created, server does not start and nothing exactly works but this silly warning.

What am I doing wrong?

UPD: When I execute this script via SSH console (Putty) everything works: file is being created and server starts in screen session. When I execute the same script via PHP ssh class it doesn't work properly.

UPD2: Both Putty and PHP script are logging in to system as non-root user. The game server has no need in running as root.

Comment: Sounds like a user account-related problem. What user is PHP running as? Can that user execute these commands?

Comment: >Web-server and CentOS Server are not on a same server!!! I mean that web-server and my VPS are separate. I use hosting provider for my web sites and use my VPS for game servers. If you mean which user does PHP use for logging in — non root user, but the directory and server executable (srcds thing) got sufficient permissions for running via this user.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (using [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/)):

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2($ssh_server, $ssh_port);
if (!$ssh->login($ssh_user, $ssh_password))
die('nologin');
//$ssh->enablePTY();
echo $ssh->exec("sh /home/...../...../za.sh");
die();
```

If that doesn't work for you try uncommenting out the `$ssh->enablePTY()`

Comment: Why do you believe that this will solve the problem?

Comment: Tried and still not working.